# Custom Object list view

Tags: custom-object, permission-sets, list-view, filters

I have a requirement to only show certain records in a list view to users based on two field values. I can filter the fields on the list view page but I have not been able to find if I can default to that custom list view filter when a certain user clicks on the tab. So if I have a user added to a permission set, I want to limit/ filter what they see when they click on the tab without having them filter themselves. Is this possible?

Comment: Curious as to the reason for the down-vote

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by looking at sharing settings. I could share records for this custom object based on field values and users in public groups.